# bouncing animation effect when click on button to move div1 out of screen and div2 to 20px from top

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations, transition, setinterval

plz help thanks in advance...sorry for bad english ... want a animation effect with bouncing when div1 and div2 goes up and down

I have made main div in which there are 2 div... div1 and div2.

I want to make it like, when someone click on button.

That time div1 should slowly move out of the screen from top side with animation (slowly moving out of the top side screen).

And at the same time div2 should take a place 20px from top of screen.

I have setup almost everything but I'm not able to give it a animation effect no wonder why but transition effect or anything not working on it. I want to do it with JavaScript code if possible I less use jQuery or etc.

I am happy to use another approach, like instead of using margin-top to move div1 out of screen and div2 to top side if you recommend any other css or javascript, that's fine. I just want the animation effect in which slowly div1 and div2 move to top side.

```js
function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.marginTop = "-110px";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.marginTop = "20px";
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.marginTop = "0px";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.marginTop = "0px";

}
```

```css
#main {
 background-color: grey;
 height: 1000px; 
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

#div1 {
 background-color: red;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
   position: relative;

 }

#div2 {
 background-color: green;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
   position: relative;

 }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  
  <div id="div1"> </div>
  
  <div id="div2"> </div>
  

  <button onclick="myFunction1()">Button 1</button>

  <button onclick="myFunction2()">Button 2</button>

</div>
```

Comment: The is a very broad question. Maybe you should look at online resources about CSS animations. css-tricks is a good place to start: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/

Comment: Otherwise, please edit your question by showing your attempts which didn't work

Comment: We like questions to be nice and readable here, so please use capital letters, and refrain from `plz` and `thx` as much as possible, using real English words instead. If you are posting from a mobile phone, it is better if you can switch to a computer with a keyboard, so it is easier to post a legible question. Thanks.

Comment: im sorry but it was my first post here. and my english is not that gud :/ anyway thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a CSS transition to your elements. You can change the parameters to taste. I believe this is the cleanest and most efficient solution.

EDIT: As per OP's request in the comments, I've shown an example of a transition function which emulates a slight "bounce" effect on the transition using extreme values. You can quickly create your own transition function and test it in real time using online tools (ex: [cubic-bezier.com](http://cubic-bezier.com/)) or the Chrome developer tools (you can click on a transition function for an element you are inspecting to edit the function in real time). Note that this functionality is currently not universally supported (see: [Safari Bug 45761](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45761))

[Transitions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

```js
function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.marginTop = "-110px";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.marginTop = "20px";
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.marginTop = "0px";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.marginTop = "0px";

}
```

```css
#main {
 background-color: grey;
 height: 1000px; 
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

/* *** THIS IS NEW *** */
#main div {
  -webkit-transition: margin 1s cubic-bezier(1,.7,.49,1.7);
          transition: margin 1s cubic-bezier(1,.7,.49,1.7);
}
/* *** END NEW *** */

#div1 {
 background-color: red;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
   position: relative;

 }

#div2 {
 background-color: green;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
   position: relative;

 }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  
  <div id="div1"> </div>
  
  <div id="div2"> </div>
  

  <button onclick="myFunction1()">Button 1</button>

  <button onclick="myFunction2()">Button 2</button>

</div>
```

Comment: i tried this same code 300 times but it wasn't working before... don't know what silly mistake i was doing... but now it is working ... i can't stop laughing :D ... thanks dear :D ... any way only last question ... do you know how to make it bouncing when animating ? up and down ? thanks again sir

Comment: There are two ways of doing this that I can think of off the top of my head. The first is to create a CSS animation using keyframes and apply it. I have no experience with this as I've never needed it, but you can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations.

The other is to define a non-standard transition function that has extreme values. I'll add an example above.